# Making libtool use another file/directory pattern

Tags: libtool

How to make libtool don't use (in compile mode) .libs folder for generated PIC object files but another one or even change the name of PIC file, for example: object-file.lo, object-file.o, object-file-pic.o -> these three in one folder.
Standard procedure:

```
$ libtool --mode=compile gcc -O -o call.o -c called.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -O -c called.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/call.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -O -c called.c -o call.o >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: You don't. libtool addresses a specific problem, which is a portable way of linking object files and maintaining object / library metadata in `.lo`, `.la` files. Breaking these conventions breaks libtool's ability to transparently link libraries / programs. This seems like an XY problem. *Why* use libtool if you're going to do this?

Comment: So why .lo files hold information about the location of these files if it's fixed?